# Test for null child before compiling Expression

Tags: c#, linq

I'm attempting to retrieve a value via an `Expression`, but I have a scenario where a child property on the model is null and I'm getting a `NullReferenceException`.

The scenario occurs where I'm using a Model in the following way, where `x` is the model in the view and it isn't null, but the `Contact` property is null:

```
x => x.Contact.Email
```

I then retrieve the value using the following:

```
public static FieldInfo Get<TModel, TProperty>(HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    object value = null;
    if (html.ViewData.Model != null)
    {
        value = expression.Compile()(html.ViewData.Model);
    }

    // other code
}
```

How can I adapt this code to test for null on the child property or is that not possible?

Comment: Ok cool. I'm on 4.5.2. I'm testing that and it's not working.  The Razor engine knows how to handle these scenarios, so I guess there's a way to do it somehow.  If all else fails, maybe a try-catch?

Comment: @Savage: since you're dealing with expressions, you have to obtain `ParameterExpression`, get its value and traverse property path yourself via reflection with appropriate null-checking. I assume, that null propagation is not an option for you, because you're writing some sort of Razor helper.

Comment: Is try-catch a bad idea?

Comment: @npinti: the problem is that OP wants something like Razor rendering helpers. It's hard to force caller to use null-propagation everywhere. Moreover, it will be just a garbage.

Comment: @Dennis: I understand now.

Comment: @Savage: actually, yes, it's a bad idea. E.g., what if model will throw NRE for any other reason? You will hide it, and it will be hard to find out, what's the problem here.

Comment: Can you add the model for `x`?

Comment: @SamW it's generic `TModel`, so the actual model type is variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to handle this in my `IQueryable` left outer join implementation, I use an `ExpressionVisitor` that replaces `null.member` with `null`. You can use something similar to test for null dynamically in your `Expression`, which is supported by EF/LINQ to SQL:

```
public static class ExpressionExt {
    public static TE AddTestForNull<TE>(this TE orig) where TE : Expression => (TE)(new NullTestVisitor().Visit(orig));
}


/// <summary>
/// ExpressionVisitor to replace a obj.member Expression with a null test ((obj == null) ? null : obj.member)
/// </summary>
public class NullTestVisitor : System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor {
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node) {
        if (node is MemberExpression nme)
            return Expression.Condition(Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, nme.Expression.AddTestForNull(), Expression.Constant(null, nme.Expression.Type)),
                                        Expression.Constant(null, nme.Type),
                                        nme);
        else
            return base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

Then when you need to handle such an `Expression`, just tack on `AddTestForNull`:

```
value = expression.AddTestForNull().Compile()(html.ViewData.Model);
```

This will add the test at every level - if you have `x => x.member.testMember`, it will be replaced with `((x == null ? null : x.member) == null ? null : x.member.testMember)`.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately I'm getting a compile error because the original post refers to type of `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>` whereas your example refers to type of `Expression`. Would you be able to adapt your answer to work in the original context?

Comment: @Savage An `Expression<Func<>>` is an `Expression` - this works fine in LINQPad. What exactly is the code and error?

Comment: `'Expression' does not contain a definition for 'Compile'...` on `expression.AddTestForNull().Compile()`

Comment: The initial `AddTestForNull` was not generic - a cast would have been required for `Compile` to work. I updated the code to make a generic version.

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible for you to adjust your Get(..) method to use a Func instead of an Expression?

Expressions do not allow Null Coalescing or Null Propagation operators. But Functions do.

```
//Yours
public static FieldInfo Get<TModel, TProperty>(HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression) { ... }

//Potential solution for you
public static FieldInfo Get<TModel, TProperty>(HtmlHelper<TModel> person, Func<TModel, TProperty> func) { ... }
```

Expressions do not allow Null Coalescing or Null Propagation operators. But Functions do.

Please excuse the difference in types. I was working with what I had easiest access to at the time to create a concrete example for you.

Notice that the Invoke() method is called instead of Compile()

```
public static object Get<Person, TProperty>(Person person, Func<Person, TProperty> func)
{
    object result = null;

    if (person != null)
    {
        result = func.Invoke(person);
    }

    return result;
}
```

### Example Use

```
var personNoContact = new Person { Contact = null };
var result = Get(personNoContact, x => x.Contact?.Email.EmailAddress ?? "");
```

### The following classes were used for testing

```
public class Person
{
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public Email Email { get; set; }
}

public class Email { public string EmailAddress { get; set; } }
```

Comment: Thanks for your submission. The trouble is we're not dealing with `List` or `IQueryable`, but with `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>`.  See if you can adapt my original method to check for null values when you're given the parameters in that method.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding the question. I updated my answer.

Comment: The trouble with this solution is that all the "dirty work" has been transferred to the caller. If you look at the way Razor is implemented, I can call `x.Contact.Email` and it takes care of the possibility of null at all levels.  I'm developing a form builder based on Razor and I'd like the same capability.

Comment: That's a tough problem on your hands. Wishing you luck! Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.